# Salesforce PHP API - can't query picklist

Tags: salesforce

I am using Salesforce API on my project, but interesting thing happens and i can query all
fields except picklists :(

Can someone help me with that?

Thankx

Comment: please attach relevant piece of code

Comment: It would be very helpful if we could see some code...also, do you mean you are unable to query the values saved in picklist fields, or you are unable to grab the list of possible values in these fields through the metadata API?

Answer (score 0):

Make changes in the xslt by adding the fields which need to display.Then it will display all the  fields you specified